# Why do I get an exception when I pass a std::string to printf?

Tags: c++, string, printf

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a[10] = "asd asd";
    char b[10] ="bsd bsd";
    string str(a);
    str.append(b);
    printf("\n--------%s--------\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

I can't understand why this produces an exception? This program mainly tries to append strings. I get the desired output when using `std::cout` but not when using `printf`.

Comment: You need to use `str.c_str()`.

Comment: GOt it......have to convert to c style string...

Comment: In C++ you should really consider using `cout`. It has a better compile-time safety comparing to `printf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `std::string` is not the same as `char const *`, which is what the `%s` format specifies.  You need to use the `c_str()` method to return the pointer expected by `printf()`:

```
printf("\n--------%s--------\n", str.c_str());
```

To be more technical, `printf()` is a function imported from the C world and it expects a "C-style string" (a pointer to a sequence of characters terminated by a null character).  `std::string::c_str()` returns such a pointer so that C++ strings can be used with existing C functions.

Answer (score 1):

c_str(). Have to use style string using this function..

Answer (score 1):

printf() handles c strings (char *), you are using a c++-style string and therefore need to convert between them.

Simply use the c_str() method like so

```
printf("%s", str.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf`s `%s` format specifier is expecting a C style string not a `std::string`, so you need to use [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) which return a `const char*`:

```
printf("\n--------%s--------\n", str.c_str());
```

Basically you have [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since `printf` will try to access your argument as if it was a pointer to a null terminated C style string. Although, since this is C++ you should just use `std::cout` is safer.